# Why is it called "rationalization"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is coming from algebra tests at the beginning of James Stewart's Calculus 6th edition.

Rationalize the expression and simplify.  The function is $(\sqrt{4 + h} - 2)/h$.  After rationalizing it, I get $$\frac{4 + h - 4}{h\sqrt{4 + h} + 2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 + h} + 2}.$$ I'm used to seeing radicals being removed from the bottom producing a rational function, but this example seems very weird.  (And this is the solution given by Stewart's book.)

**Footnote**.  How is this resulting function any better than the problem's function, by the way?  I would not say this is a rational function because the bottom of the fraction is not a polynomial.  It seems to me that this exercise is misclassified or I don't know what "rationalization" really means.

Comment: What you're calling rationalization doesn't make a lot of sense to me: that usually refers to forming a rational function whose denominator has no radicals in it. But that's already true for $(\sqrt{4+h}-2)/h$, so it's already "rationalized". By contrast, the rationalization of $h/(\sqrt{4+h}-2)$ is $$\frac{h}{\sqrt{4+h}-2}\frac{\sqrt{4+h}+2}{\sqrt{4+h}+2}=\frac{h(\sqrt{4+h}+2)}{4+h-4}=\sqrt{4+h}+2.$$

Comment: There may be confusion with terminology. When you write *"I'm used to seeing radicals being removed from the bottom"*, perhaps you're referring to *rationalizing the denominator*; eg, 
$$\frac1{\sqrt3}\cdot\frac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt3}\to\frac{\sqrt3}{3} \qquad  \frac{5}{3-\sqrt7}\cdot\frac{3+\sqrt7}{3+\sqrt7}\to\frac{5(3+\sqrt7)}2$$ It's a bit of algebraic tidying-up, because fractions can be more palatable when their denominators are radical-free. (continued)

Comment: (continuing) But there's no reason we couldn't "rationalize the *numerator*" if it suits our purpose; and, with limit exercises like the one you cite, it *does*. As with many elementary limits, the goal is to cleverly manipulate a "$0/0$" expression in such a way that the $0$ cancels; there, you want to cancel the $h$, but the numerator's $h$ is trapped under a radical. By *rationalizing the numerator*, you make the numerator nicer (and can cancel the $h$); the denominator is *uglier*, but at least it's not *problematic* —substituting $h=0$ won't make it zero— so we'll take it.

Comment: (continuing2) Back to the terminological point: one might use the term "rationalizing" without specifying numerator or denominator as an umbrella term for either case (because writing "rationalizing the numerator or denominator" becomes tedious quickly). Even so, the result is not necessarily a *rational function*. What matters is that a particularly pesky part of the function has become radical-free.

Comment: Got it!  I see what's going on now.  FWIW, I think we should call the process simply as "deradicalization".  Your numerator and denominator explanation is making sense to me now.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @user1145880: "deradicalization" is a reasonable alternative. "rationalization" derives from how the process is introduced w/ elementary *numerical* fractional expressions involving integers. Since an irreducible radical of an integer is necessarily irrational, "deradicalization" amounts to "de-irrationalization"; more simply, "rationalization". The term loses its literal meaning once exotic numbers and/or variable expressions enter the fray. A thoughtful instructor or author would take care to discuss the terminological nuances. "deradicalization" has the advantage of lacking such nuance. :)